# jqplot DateAxisRenderer and timestamps not working in IE/FF

Tags: jqplot

I am using timestamps values for xaxis in this format: `var timestamp = 1201662065000`

Under Chrome it works but in `FF.17/IE8` it just renders chart grid with y-axis but it doesnt render x-axis and series (the plot). So it doesn't give any error but it doesn't render my chart...

I think it must be something with date-parsing, maybe its different in FF/IE?

Answer (score 0):

You must do something wrong. Here is a fiddle I made to show you an example : http://jsfiddle.net/Bouillou/WdLnm/291/

In some cases, Chrome is a very nice browser which correct automatically html errors (like lack of end marker ) or aberration like define a form in a table outside cell (). Other browsers will just not execute the code.

My advice is : test your code with HTML validator.

Here is the xaxis code portion :

```
            xaxis:
            {
                label: 'Dates',
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                rendererOptions: { tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer },
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '%d/%m/%Y',
                    angle: -30,
                    fontFamily: 'Arial',
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                min: "01-01-2012",
                tickInterval: '2 month',
                labelOptions: {
                    fontFamily: 'Arial',
                    fontSize: '14pt',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    textColor: '#0070A3'
                }
            },
```

And data used :

```
 var data = [[1325376000000, 1], [1350864000000, 2], [1354320000000, 3]];
```